# simple text based hangman in python

Tags: python

I'm working on a simple text based hangman game in python.  I have a rough program running but I've encountered two minor problems:

1. Why does the welcome message print twice?
2. When the user inputs a letter not in the word two times in a row, the second time, the `"nope, try again"`-message does not display and current word does not display.  The first time an incorrect letter is input, it works.  Why doesn't it work the second time?

---

```
from random import randrange

class HangmanApp:

    def __init__(self, interface):

        self.infile = open("hangman.txt", "r")
        self.interface = textInterface()

        for line in self.infile:
            self.wordlist = line.split()
        self.secretword = self.wordlist[randrange(len(self.wordlist))]

        self.letter_list = list(self.secretword)



    #tests the user's guess

    def guess(self):

        self.new_list = ["_"]*len(self.secretword)

        #keep loop going as long as there are letters in the list
        while self.letter_list != ["_"]*len(self.letter_list):                

            self.guess = self.interface.guess()

            if self.guess in self.letter_list:

                while self.guess in self.letter_list:

                    i = self.letter_list.index(self.guess)

                    #replace that letter from the list with "_" 
                    self.letter_list[self.letter_list.index(self.guess)] = "_"

                    #add the chosen letter to a new list for display
                    self.new_list[i] = self.guess                                   

                    #print list with letter added
                    self.interface.correct(self.new_list)                           

            else:

                self.interface.incorrect(self.new_list)

                self.guess = self.interface.guess()

class textInterface:

    def __init__(self):
        print("Welcome to Hangman!")

    def guess(self):
        guess = input("Guess a letter! ")
        return guess

    def display (self, word):
        string = ' '.join(word)
        print(string)

    def incorrect(self, word):
        print("Nope, try again")
        self.display(word)

    def correct(self, word):
        print("Correct")
        self.display(word)


    def main():
        inter = textInterface()
        app = HangmanApp(inter)
        app.guess()
```

Comment: Well the welcome message will print twice because you create two instances of the `textInterface` class. When you instantiate `HangmanApp` don't you want to assign the `interface` argument to `self.interface` rather than create a new instance?

Comment: I recommend you learn how to use a debugger, this greatly helps with these kinds of problems.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Sorry, I haven't seen any mention of the debugger in the text that I'm using.  Do you know of a decent tutorial for it?

Comment: You should do this from your IDE. If you don't use an IDE, [choose one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/). If you insist on command line, check [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The welcome message is printed twice because you're creating two instances of `textInterface`: one in `main()` and another inside `HangmanApp.__init__()`. I think you meant to do:

```
self.interface = interface
```

instead of

```
self.interface = textInterface()
```

Inside `HangmanApp.guess()`, after receiving an incorrect guess (reaching the `else:` clause) you have an extra `guess` prompt that is not needed---one that doesn't pass through your checking code. I think this is probably causing the issue with it not working the second time around.